# Page Elements gets visible when click on Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

Here is my website link : [LINK](http://honkytonk.in/) : Some of page elements are not visible initially but when I right click on page and then click on Inspect Element then all the elements start showing up. I have been trying to find the bug but couldn't find yet. Can anyone help me what should I do? Website is in CakePHP.

**EDIT:**
Screen resize also works.

Screenshot is attached.
[image]

Comment: what element exactly?

Comment: Text elements are not showing up. When I click on F12 or do screen resize then everything showing up. You can check the online link

Comment: I'm on it. It seems everything is fine. Maybe you'd better to give us a picture of what you mean.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot how its coming on my system and other systems.

Comment: This is how it looks like on my system http://tinypic.com/r/6jm61i/8

Comment: Your problem is with fonts. what if you wait a little longer? will they show up?

Comment: Yes, it is working on some systems but not all. If it is not working on a system then screen resize do the magic or inspect element.

Comment: You're loading gazzilion of things at once. The fonts need some time. Btw. I've never seen a header with that many calls in my life!

Comment: No, they never come if I wait a little longer.

Comment: can you see this file? http://honkytonk.in/croogo/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Yes, I can see. @MostafaShahverdy Actually, it is a client website and I can't remove the JS or CSS files.

Comment: I'm just checking if they are loading in your browser. How about font/fontawesome-webfont.eot? Is it loading in your browser?

Comment: How should I check? I didn't get. Sorry.

Comment: Open the related files in your browser and see if they load. Just make sure there are not errors in chrome console. pressing F12 will get you to the console.

Comment: Don't know what is happening. I am looking at Network call and its showing all the calls but with 0 B size for some elements. You can try in other browsers using browserstack application online.

Comment: I am getting these errors in console. Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi) 
Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. %7Bmain,places%7D.js:54
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: every thing sounds working. clear you cache from app/tmp/cache/model/all files here AND ALSO app/tmp/cache/persistent/ Files here

Comment: may i see your code? -there might be a problem with your layout. there should be a condition in your layout or one of view that of browser is IE then don't show the element

Comment: I have already provided online link in my question. Please look over that.

Comment: I don't want that link that doesn't work. I need pure code to see what's wrong with you imports.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/T0ke2WPH

Answer (score 0):

It seems some resource loading issues. Make sure you are loading the javascript files at end of the page and stylesheets at begining.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is are some conflictions in your head which breaks your body tag. there are lots of problem with your layout. The fastest solution is try to recode you layout and test it with IE.

1) there are many imported plugins try to comment them group by group to see if one of them is not working with IE

2) all the css and js imports should be based on cakephp import. try to follow the role the it will be easy for you to test.

3)check if all the tags are closed. xhtml standard

4) if it's possible try to load your plugins at the end of the page - so you checked all your tags is loaded then assign the plugins.

5) I can see website loading is very slow. try to use less plugins and use each plugin and js in view of it's page. I can see you used all the validation for different pages in you layout. or other things